# Method Specific Constants in Java

Tags: java, constants

Is it possible to have a constant variable that is local only to a specific method? It seems unnecessary to put it at the class level when it is only used in one method. Using the "final" modifier in the method will prevent the variable from being modified after it is initialized, but it will be re-initialized every time the method is called, even when it is unnecessary. Is there a way to make it static? For example, in the following code, "calculating" is printed every time the doStuff method is called:

```
public void doStuff() { 
    final int myVar = getNum();
    ...
}

public int getNum() {
    System.out.println("calculating");
    return 2;
}
```

Can "myVar" be initialized once, say, when the class is loaded without being outside of the method?

This is mostly out of curiosity. Is this something that is ever done or suggested?

Comment: No.  C and C++ have this, but not Java.

Comment: C# is another language that supports local constants (and is a modern, managed language like Java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods in Java cannot have static variables at this time.

> Is this something that is ever done or suggested?

Some other languages (C, C++) have this. It does provide additional encapsulation of data. For example, in C++ it is the canonical lazy-instantiated singleton:

```
Singleton const* Singleton::instance() {
    const static Singleton instance;
    return &instance;
}
```

I'm not aware it is a proposed feature for Java.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of declaring a static variable which can only be used within a single method. It is not part of the Java syntax.

You could do this at your class level with `final static` modifiers. It will be initialized to a static constant on the class and since it is `final`, cannot be changed once set:

```
public class MyClass {
    private static final int myVar = 2;
    ...
}
```

From [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

> The static modifier, in combination with the final modifier, is also
>   used to define constants. The final modifier indicates that the value
>   of this field cannot change.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I was actually wondering if it could be done at the method level. Obviously I could put it at the class level and achieve the same effect, but could I also do it this way? If classes can have final static variables, can methods?

Answer (score 0):

"Is it possible to have a constant variable that is local only to a specific method?"  First, ***constant variable*** is a commonly used term, but it is an oxymoron. Something *constant* cannot change, and a *variable* has the ability to change.  A *constant field* or *constant data member* might be more appropriate terms.  The question then becomes, why do you need a *constant* inside a method?  After all, even if you make the *constant field* public, it will not change, so its scope becomes a bit irrelevant.

In practice, *constant fields* are often made static (not always).  Going back to your question, can it be done?  The following is valid code:

```
public class ConstantDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ConstantDemo demo = new ConstantDemo();        
        for (int i = 1; i <=12; i++)
            System.out.println("7 times " + i + " equals " + demo.timesSeven(i));
    }

    public int timesSeven(int number)
    {
        final int x = 7;
        return number * x;
    }
}
```

The question is, what do you really accomplish by limiting the scope of this *constant field*?  As Radiodef suggested, methods cannot have static fields declared inside (in Java).

Comment: As I said, it was mostly out of curiosity, but also it seems like this would make for cleaner code. Say there are several constant fields that are used exclusively in a single method. I was wondering if it were necessary to clutter the rest of the class with them.

Comment: @Camander The general rule is to limit the scope of variables as much as possible.  Could this rule apply to constants? Maybe. The problem you can run into is over-declaration of the same values over and over. In that case, it will do more harm than good.  Also, instead of a local *constant field* you can use a literal value.  For example, in the code above, the method body could be simplified to one line: `return number * 7;`. No need for local constants.

Comment: While it doesn't make a whole lot of sense, *'constant variable'* is [official terminology](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4).

Comment: @Radiodef I never said that the term is not official. I just stated that it is an oxymoron, which it is. It was necessary to establish a clear separation between "variables" and "constants" to make my point.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you only accomplish the single instantiation by having the variable initialized outside the method. Otherwise as other people have noted it's not possible to have the static var local to the method.

```
public class Example {

    public static final int myVar2 = getNum();

    public void doStuff() { 
        System.out.println("In doStuff: myVar = " + myVar2);
    }

    public static final int getNum() {
        System.out.println("calculating");
        return 2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Example ex = new Example();

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            ex.doStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

The output from such a construct is as follows.

`calculating
In doStuff: myVar = 2
In doStuff: myVar = 2
In doStuff: myVar = 2
In doStuff: myVar = 2
In doStuff: myVar = 2`

As you can see it accomplish the static instantiation.

Comment: As others have pointed out however this only accomplished the static initialization but it can be used by other methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible since Java 16 using local classes with static fields:

```
private static void doStuff() {
    class Holder {
        static final int myVar = getNum(); // Will be initialized once

        private static int getNum() {
            ...
        }
    }

    // Use Holder.myVar
}
```